# How to run ng serve at cmd prompt

Tags: npm

When I run ng serve at cmd prompt I get an error saying

```
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I've tried 'ng serve' and "ng serve" but neither are working. I've noticed that npm start does run ng serve though, but I was wondering how I could get ng serve to run also.

Thanks

Comment: This is the command prompt in windows, right? Make sure the directory ng is in is in your path. Type "path" to see your current path.

Comment: I didn't see the directory in my path. Would you have to install npm globally for the ng serve directory to appear in the path?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the first part of your question. Yes, this is the cmd prompt in windows.

Comment: Yes, definitely install it globally if you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

For running ng serve, be safe to start the cmd prompt in the right file directory, e.g. ng5 (where angular.js is)